# How to update TextEditingController text inside build?

Tags: flutter

`TextEditingController.text` has the following docs:

> Setting this will notify all the listeners of this [TextEditingController] that they need to update (it calls [notifyListeners]). For this reason, this value should only be set between frames,  e.g. in response to user actions, not during the build, layout, or paint phases.
>
> This property can be set from a listener added to this [TextEditingController]; however, one  should not also set [selection] in a separate statement. To change both the [text] and the  [selection] change the controller's [value].

How am I supposed to update the `TextEditingController.text` inside a `build` method if I want then?

Also, is this limitation regarding performance issues, as to no lock up the `build` method with the listeners execution? Or is it something else?

Comment: Why do you need to edit the text in a build method? You can update the actual field's initial value via a function. Logic should NEVER be in your build() method as it can get called at any time for any reason.

Comment: I think "NEVER" is too much, but I agree in general, I guess in my case I could make it differently, but still, my question remains as a general line of thought. Is it so impossible to think on a case were someone would like to update the `text` inside a `build`? Maybe it's related to an `AnimatedWidget`, I don't know

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems impossible to update the text in the build() method. Still, I can't see a reason to update the text in that method. I would do it in initState() or atleast a method that gets called from it with data to update the initial value with.

Comment: It doesn't sound as impossible to me, as I have done and it works, I think it's more like a recommendation, I wanted to know the extent of this recommendation, so I can evaluate the side effects for myself.